# Restricting User based on GeoLocation in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, geolocation, ip-geolocation

in my asp.net mvc app i have a survey Model that can be created by anyone. Moreover, i want people from specific part of world to participate (vote) in the survey. It is easy job if i know the location (it could be city, country or state etc.). i want to add this location restriction at the time of survey creation (i.e user could tell that people of Islamabad or punjab or Pakistan) could vote or fill out this survey form. Moreover, i want to add that location restriction is applicable (or expected) for small number of surveys (5 percent at most) so how to most efficiently implement this functionality.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this a couple of ways:

1. Determine where the user is from based on a previous question asking their location. Not bullet proof as the user could easily say they are from somewhere they are not.
2. Obtain an IP -> Country mapping list that will provide you a lookup of the customer's IP address vs. their location. You would restrict based on this.

Comment: +1 for option 2 but what about restriction checking for 100% surveys whereas restriction applies only to 5% of suverys

Comment: restriction may be on level of city, country, state etc. How can i control this scenario when creating the survey and when survey is posted by end user

Answer (score 2):

You can figure out someone's location using IP address. There are many services out there that offer IP address location. They will give you an approximation of the users location based on that.

[Here](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php) is an example of the service:

You can also get their location using HTML5 geolocation [features](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/geolocation.html).

For your case using IP address is probably good enough. The HTML5 option is nice because if the user doesn't have a GPS device on their system it eventually falls back to using IP address location.

In order to get a users IP address in ASP.NET you can use

```
Request.Servervariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
```

Comment: +1 for html-5 feature. can u plz consider my comment on Matthew's answer